# Sqlite select and create new column

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table called "tweets_words_pairs". Attached below is a snippet of the table

["tweets_words_pairs" table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQYgR.png)

I want to count how many times a word appears in each tweet, and then add it into a new column called "word_count". so a snippet of an example output for the very first id is shown below

| id | tweet_id | word | word_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1408411651238371337 | three | 1 |
| 2 | 1408411651238371337 | incorrect | 1 |
| 3 | 1408411651238371337 | assumptions | 1 |
| 4 | 1408411651238371337 | climate | 1 |
| 5 | 1408411651238371337 | change | 1 |
| 6 | 1408411651238371337 | tieh | 1 |

This is what  i currently have right now

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame() #create dataframe
conn = sqlite3.connect('tweets_data.sqlite')
curr = conn.cursor() 
curr.execute("SELECT tweet_id, COUNT(word) FROM tweet_word_pairs")
rows = curr.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

However my output (shown below) is wrong, and i am unsure of how to create a new column for the table as i am a beginner to this

```
(1408411651238371337, 11802)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `GROUP BY` in your aggregate query, so the aggregate expression `COUNT(word)` is evaluated for the whole table, while the non-aggregate expression `tweet_id` is evaluated once for a random row (this is a SQLite feature).

```
SELECT tweet_id, word, COUNT(*) AS word_count 
FROM tweet_word_pairs
GROUP BY tweet_id, word
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to add the column "word_count" and its values permanently into the table within the same  SELECT statement?

Comment: a 'SELECT' can not change the table structure or the data, you need to first  `ALTER TABLE` then `UPDATE`, but I'm not sure if it makes sens to have both the original  and the aggregated data in the same table

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would do it?